# safari video load error

Tags: html, performance, safari, html5-video

I used the following code to embed a video in Safari.

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <canvas id="introCanvas"></canvas>
     <video id="introVideo" src="img/test12.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

Looking at the dev tools, I saw that there is some loading error. And that the Video loads three times. Anyone an idea what this could be?

[image: screenshot showing loading error]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

206 response codes are not errors. (Only the 400- and 500-series codes are errors.) Response code 206 means "here are a some bytes which partially fulfill your request, so you can start playing your video, but there'll be more".)

Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206

Hope this helps.